# How do I access an application in Websphere application server cluster?

Tags: websphere, cluster-computing

I am trying to set up an websphere application server cluster and deploy an web application on it. I have successfully run the application on a standalone websphere server in a standalone node. Now I have created the cluster including nodes, and deployed my application on it. The question is now how to access the application in browser. In standalone install, punching in the default host port and application context in the browser was enough. What should I do now ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would front the application server cluster with a web server such as IHS, Apache (to name a couple)

The Web Server will look at the plugin config XML (generated by the Deployment manager and copied to the Web Server machine) and do the load balancing activity.

The browser would be pointing to the Web Server now (and not the Application Server directly).

HTH

Comment: Thanks a lot. I installed IHS along with web server plugin for was, and now the requests are being routed in round robin manner.